# Hide or show between two div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 `<div>` say it `div1` and `div2`. before I click submit I want `div1` will `show` and `div2` will `hide` but after I click submit, `div1` will `hide` and `div2` will `show`

My code in kanjiconverter.php

```
   <?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){
        $kanji = ($_POST['convertkanji']);

        $replacements = [
        'class="rt">' => "",
        ];
        $newkanji = strtr($kanji, $replacements);
  }
?>
```

my form code

```
<form id="convertkanji" method="post" action="kanjiconverter.php"></form>
        <form>
          <div class="form-row">

            <!-- START DIV1 HERE -->
          <div id="div1" class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="convertkanji">Kanji Convert</label>
            <textarea id="convertkanji1" name="convertkanji" rows="10" form="convertkanji"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" name="submit1" class="btn btn-default" form="convertkanji" value="Convert" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 6px;" />
          </div>
          <!-- Ended DIV1 HERE -->

          <!-- START DIV2 HERE -->
            <div id="div2" class="form-group col-md-6" style="display: none;">
      <label for="kanji">New Kanji</label>
      <textarea id="kanji" name="kanji" rows="12" form="tambahposting"><?php echo $newkanji ?></textarea>
    </div>
          <!-- Ended DIV2 HERE -->
    </form>
```

and jquery script here

```
      <script>
        $(function() {
  $('#div1').show();
  $('#div2').hide();

  $('input[name="submit1"]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();


    $('#div1').hide();
    $('#div2').show();

    $.post('kanjiconverter.php', $('form').serialize(), function(response) {
      //Your response from the server-side
    })
  });
});
      </script>
```

i place jquery code above `<html>` and `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` in `head` tag.

between show and hide is working, but when i click submit button i dont get any data.

Comment: So what have you tried, if anything?  Also are you planning on doing ajax?  Because a form submit would cause a page transition so the showing of div2 after would be pointless if not doing ajax.

Comment: Please post your attempts to achive that..

Answer (score 0):

You must attach a `click` or `submit` event to your submit button then send the data to your server side using ajax request to prevent the page from refreshing and `hide/show` the divs you want inside the event.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#div1').show();
  $('#div2').hide();

  $('input[name="submit1"]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();


    $('#div1').hide();
    $('#div2').show();

    $.post('php_file.php', $('form').serialize(), function(response) {
      //Your response from the server-side
    })
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <div class="form-row">
    <!-- START DIV1 HERE -->
    <div id="div1" class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="convertkanji">Kanji Convert</label>
      <textarea id="convertkanji1" name="convertkanji" rows="10" form="convertkanji"></textarea>
      <input type="submit" name="submit1" class="btn btn-default" form="convertkanji" value="Convert" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 6px;" />
    </div>
    <!-- Ended DIV1 HERE -->

    <!-- START DIV2 HERE -->
    <div id="div2" class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="kanji">New Kanji</label>
      <textarea id="kanji" name="kanji" rows="12" form="tambahposting"><?php echo $newkanji ?></textarea>
    </div>
    <!-- Ended DIV2 HERE -->
</form>
```

Comment: so, i have to create a php file to proccess submit? in my submit code i dont need to modify it?

Comment: You should put the _My submit code_ section in a PHP file, then just call it in you request instead of  `php_file.php`.

Comment: You must check your Browser Network Tab to make sure the request sent successfully or not...

Comment: if u mean by inspecct elemen and network tab, when i click preview it showing nothing.

Comment: Zakaria, my earlier comment was caught in a question deletion just now, so I'm reproducing it here. As a volunteer editor, can I ask you to make posts a [bit less chatty](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A4281779+hope+helps)? It would save a bit of work, which mounts up incrementally with each additional pleasantry, and in any case, we try to aim for succinct here as much as we can. I imagine there are not many contributors who hope their posts do not help `:-)`.

Comment: Thanks for your intervention @halfer ... It just become a habit :D as [Posted on behalf of the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A472495+Posted+on+behalf+of+the+OP) for you ...

Comment: @Zakaria: if you have a critique of my posting, I am very happy to hear it. In fact, that very phrase has [been discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356951). Are you of the opinion it is a pleasantry that adds no meaning to an answer? I am very happy to understand why you have drawn attention to it, if you are willing to explain.

Comment: Hi @ZakariaAcharki: apologies, I had interpreted your reply above as agreeing with my suggestion, but I see now that you are continuing to add chatty material to your posts, and this is not really the technical style that is preferred here. Fluff material is expected of newcomers, but not experienced users. You're on ~1700 of them now - is there any chance you could desist?

Comment: (You did not outline an objection to my phrasing that you drew attention to - it does have a meaning, and it is required in order to add some attribution to moved/quoted material. But, you already knew that).